# How to interrupt or cancel promises in order to clean up multiple objects created asynchronously in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, es6-promise, cancellation

**Note**: My code happens to be in TypeScript, but this question applies to both TypeScript and JavaScript with a few syntactic changes.

I've got a class that subscribes to a few things (such as Autobahn messages). When I'm done with the object, I need to unsubscribe from everything. Generically, my code is something like this:

```
class Example {
    private sub1: Subscription;
    private sub2: Subscription;
    private sub3: Subscription;

    constructor() {
        subscribeToThings();
    }

    async subscribeToThings() {
        this.sub1 = await subscribeToThingOne();
        this.sub2 = await subscribeToThingTwo();
        // *** NOTE 1 ***
        this.sub3 = await subscribeToThingThree();
    }

    cleanupOnDeath () {
        this.sub1.unsubscribe();
        this.sub2.unsubscribe();
        this.sub3.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

When I no longer need this object, I call `cleanupOnDeath`.

However, there is a problem. If the subscriptions (which are asynchronous) take a long time, it's possible that the "cleanupOnDeath()" function will be called before all of `sub1`, `sub2`, and `sub3` are set. For example, the code might be at the line marked `*** NOTE 1 ***` when cleanupOnDeath is called.

Of course I could check if each one is undefined or not, before calling `unsubscribe`, **but that doesn't really solve things** because then that third subscription gets processed *after* `cleanupOnDeath` is finished, and lives forever.

Is there a way to implement this code so that `cleanupOnDeath()` can be be called in the middle of `subscribeToThings()` without making the code incredibly complex?

The simplest solution I have been able to come up with is something like this (replacing the sections of the above code as appropriate):

```
    constructor() {
        this.subscribeAndUnsubscribe();
    }

    async subscribeAndUnsubscribe () {
        await this.subscribeToThings();

        await cleanupEvent.wait();

        this.sub1.unsubscribe();
        this.sub2.unsubscribe();
        this.sub3.unsubscribe();
    }

    cleanupOnDeath() {
        cleanupEvent.set();
    }
```

Where `cleanupEvent` is some kind of synchronization primitive. But I don't think this is optimal, because it also requires all pending subscriptions to be completed before any can be unsubscribed. Ideally, I'd like to be able to abort `subscribeToThings()` early, without adding checks after every line of code. For example. it can be done like this:

```
    completed:boolean = false;

    async subscribeToThings() {
        try {
           this.abortIfDone();
           this.sub1 = await subscribeToThingOne();
           this.abortIfDone();
           this.sub2 = await subscribeToThingTwo();
           this.abortIfDone();
           this.sub3 = await subscribeToThingThree();
        } catch (abortedEarly) {
           // Something here
        }
    }

    abortIfDone() {
        if (this.completed) throw 'Something';
    }

    cleanupOnDeath() {
        this.completed = true;
        if (this.sub1) this.sub1.unsubscribe();
        if (this.sub1) this.sub2.unsubscribe();
        if (this.sub1) this.sub3.unsubscribe();
    }
```

But that is messy and complicated.

#### Edit - Solution

I ended up using the following code, based on @ChrisTavares's answer.  The  difference between this and his answer is that I am no longer awaiting anything or storing the subscriptions themselves. Before, I was awaiting them to get the underlying subscription objects, for the sole purpose of unsubscribing later. Since this code stores the promises and handles unsubscribe on those using `then`, there is no need to do that.

```
class Example {
    private sub1Promise: Promise<Subscription>;
    private sub2Promise: Promise<Subscription>;
    private sub3Promise: Promise<Subscription>;

    constructor() {
        this.subscribeToThings();
    }

    subscribeToThings() {
        // No longer async!
        this.sub1Promise = subscribeToThingOne();
        this.sub2Promise = subscribeToThingTwo();
        this.sub3Promise = subscribeToThingThree();
    }

    cleanupOnDeath () {
        this.sub1Promise.then(s => s.unsubscribe());
        this.sub2Promise.then(s => s.unsubscribe());
        this.sub3Promise.then(s => s.unsubscribe());
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there's no good solution for ES6 promises. You might want to check out [my Creed fork with its cancellation support](https://github.com/bergus/creed/blob/cancellation/cancellation.md), though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard way to cancel a promise - there's discussions going on in the various spec committees, but it's a hard problem for lots of reasons that don't help here.

I do question if this is a legitimate issue - are subscriptions really slow enough to worry about this issue? I'm not familiar with Autobahn.

But, assuming it is, one thing that could work would be to not `await` the stuff immediately, but instead to hold onto the actual promises. Then you can tack a `.then` handler to clean stuff up when needed. Something like this:

```
class Example {
    private sub1: Subscription;
    private sub2: Subscription;
    private sub3: Subscription;

    private sub1Promise: Promise<Subscription>;
    private sub2Promise: Promise<Subscription>;
    private sub3Promise: Promise<Subscription>;

    constructor() {
        subscribeToThings();
    }

    async subscribeToThings() {
        // *** NOTE - no await here ***
        this.sub1Promise = subscribeToThingOne();
        this.sub2Promise = subscribeToThingTwo();
        this.sub3Promise = subscribeToThingThree();

        this.sub1 = await this.sub1Promise;
        this.sub2 = await this.sub2Promise;
        this.sub3 = await this.sub3Promise;
    }

    cleanupOnDeath () {
        // Unsubscribe each promise. Don't need to check for null,
        // they were set in subscribeToThings
        this.sub1Promise.then((s) => s.unsubscribe());
        this.sub2Promise.then((s) => s.unsubscribe());
        this.sub3Promise.then((s) => s.unsubscribe());
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case, you should hoverever do `([this.sub1, this.sub2, this.sub3] = await Promise.all([this.sub1Promise, this.sub2Promise, this.sub3Promise]));`

Comment: To answer your question "Are subscriptions really slow enough to worry about this issue?": Yes, I've noticed this in actual use. Subscribing to a topic requires a round-trip over the Internet, and when I'm subscribing to several topics, it's possible for a user to navigate to a different section of my Angular 4 application before all the the subscriptions for that part finish (particularly if they clicked on that section by mistake and change their mind).

Comment: I do like this solution overall. If the promises were all kept in a single array, it'd make things simpler still, without needing extra variables. I like how Bergi's addition lets all of the subscriptions be processed in parallel, also--as a side benefit, that would speed things up quite a bit.

Comment: You could certainly collect the promises into a single array - I wanted to be more explicit in the solution so you correlate back to your original question.

Comment: Yes, certainly; it is appreciated. I wrote them in my question as separate variables for clarity, as well.

Comment: @ChrisTavares In fact, with this solution there's no need to "await" anything, or store the actual subscriptions themselves. I was only awaiting them and storing the subscriptions so that I could call `.unsubscribe` on them later. Here, that's handled instead by the `.then(...)` on the promises themselves. This is a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another solutions is to run logic of subscribeToThings method via synchronous executor [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs). It is not promise-basesd, therefore no need to cancel promises. But it tracks currently running slow functions with callbacks, and allows to free resources, occupied by them (e.g. issue xhr.abort, or clearTimeout) in case if caller function is requested to stop. Here is how it could be done:

Step 1. Wrap underlying function with callback into nsynjs-aware wrapper. See *wait* and *ajaxGetJson* functions in this example: https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/blob/master/examples/browser-ajax-seq.js

Step 2. Put subscription logic into separate function:

```
function syn_SubscribeToThings() {
    function subscribeToThingOne() {
        ...
        var data = ajaxGetJson(nsynjsCtx,'subscribe/url1').data;
        ...
    };
    function subscribeToThingOneTwo {
        ...
        var data = ajaxGetJson(nsynjsCtx,'subscribe/url2').data;
        ...
    };
    function subscribeToThingOneThree {
        ...
        var data = ajaxGetJson(nsynjsCtx,'subscribe/url3').data;
        ...
    };
    subscribeToThingOne();
    subscribeToThingOneTwo();
    subscribeToThingOneThree();
}
```

Step 3. Run that function via nsynjs form your subscribeToThings method:

```
subscribeToThings() {
    this.subscribeCtx = nsynjs.run(syn_SubscribeToThings,{},function(){});
}
```

Step 4. Stop it whenever you need:

```
cleanupOnDeath () {
    this.subscribeCtx.stop();
}
```

It will stop execution of syn_SubscribeToThings and cancel all active underlying callbacks automatically.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution, and may be safer overall once in place. However, having to write all those extra nested functions so that nsynjs can parse them and build its synjsBin tree starts to stray into a level of metaprogramming that I'd prefer to avoid unless necessary. It's a close call. I would be more amenable to it were it implemented as a first-class language feature, but as-is, it's yet another thing for the maintenance programmers to figure out and remember to use properly.